# Selenium function with multiprocessing

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I have written functin based on selenium and I want it to parse simultaneously multiple webpages. I have list of urls that I pass to the function that I want scrape at the same time so as to save time.

I created scraper.py file where i put scraper function:

```
def parser_od(url):
    price=[]
    url_of = url
    driver.get(url_of)
    try:
        price.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]").text.replace(" ","").replace("zł","").replace(",","."))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        price.append("")
```

Now I want to use the function to parse multiple urls from my urls at the same time using `multiprocessing` library:

```
from scraper import *
url_list=['https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/2-duze-pokoje-we-wrzeszczu-do-zamieszania-ID42f6s',
 'https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/mieszkanie-na-zamknietym-osiedlu-z-ogrodkiem-ID40ZxM',
 'https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/zaciszna-nowe-mieszkanie-3-pokoje-0-ID41UaX',
 'https://www.otodom.pl/oferta/dwupoziomowe-dewel-mieszkanie-101-m2-lebork-i-p-ID3JEcQ']

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Admin\chromedriver.exe")

from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(4) as p:
    price = p.map(parser_od, url_list)
```

But I get following error:

```
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined
```

Which is weird because chrome is opened up.

Edit:
I need to have the browser(s) open while running this scraper, so that the driver is opened before not everytime this function is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just should probably just split up the list of urls you want to process ino 4 equal parts, and have a `driver` for each process that processes one of the equal parts in the `Pool`.

```
def parser_od(urls, thread_index):
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Admin\chromedriver.exe")
    prices = []
    for i in range(len(urls)):
        url = urls[i]
        if i % 4 == thread_index:

            price=[]
            url_of = url
            driver.get(url_of)
            try:
                price.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]").text.replace(" ","").replace("zł","").replace(",","."))
            except NoSuchElementException:
                price.append("")
         prices.append(price)
    return prices

from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(4) as p:
    price = p.map(lambda x: parser_od(x, url_list), list(range(len(url_list))))
```

Comment: But in this case it will open and close the browser every time the function runs. Is it possible to open four instances of Chrome and then paraellize the funcion? I want to keep the browser open

Comment: Are you sure? I get 4 different windows that all open at the same time. I will update my answer to include some code - just a sec

Comment: But if you have more than 4 urls in list they keep opening forever

Comment: Easy and slow: just add `driver.close()` add the end of `parser_od`, then your windows will close. Faster but more work: Reuse the drivers. Instead of using `multiprocessing` you should switch to `multithreading`, because you'll want to create a list of drivers the `Threads` can all potentially use, and then implement a mechanism using `Locks` to make sure `Threads` use drivers that aren't being used by other `Threads`.

Comment: The second option looks like something that I was looking for.

Comment: But that's probably too much work. It's prob easier to just split your list in 4 equal parts and let every thread handle each part on its own. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: But does it still open new browser window after part of 4? Because everytime new browser window pops up i get some warning (workstation limitation) thats why I'm trying to use 4 windows only and let them update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198886/discussion-between-frederik-bode-and-alex-t).

Comment: While a code-only answer may answer the question, it would be a lot more useful to future readers if you explained what you changed and why.

Comment: Explanation got deleted when I edited my code - thanks for the heads up.